# Android Reside menu item disable or Hide?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

**Problem:** 
I am not able to disable `ResideMenu` item. How should I approach this problem?

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ResideMenu resideMenu;
    private ResideMenuItem itemLogout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resideMenu=new ResideMenu(this);
        resideMenu.setBackground(R.drawable.background_img_jpeg);
        resideMenu.attachToActivity(this);
        resideMenu.setMenuListener(menuListener);
        resideMenu.setScaleValue(0.6f);

        //adding the item in reside menu 
        itemLogout=new ResideMenuItem(this,R.drawable.icon_logout,"Logout");
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemLogout,ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        ...
    }
}
```

How to remove or disable this menu item when user navigates to next `Fragment` or add a new menu item?

Comment: You can add `reside menu` in `activity` only . so you need to convert `fragment` to activity where you can add new `reside menu`

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: welcome does it solve your probelm?

Comment: No, i don't want to change all fragments into activity.

Comment: If you're using https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu, I don't believe you can hide or disable menu items. It's a very limited implementation.

Comment: check out this : https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu/issues/125 @HarpreetSingh